# How to update webpack plugins with breaking changes from v4 to v5?

Tags: webpack, migration, webpack-5, webpack-config

From webpack's official migration tutorial: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

> **Update outdated options**
>
> Update the following options to their new version (if used):

[image]

Does it mean that those plugins will no longer exist as actual plugins?

What I mean:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

const config = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedChunksPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

Should be converted to the following config?

```
const config = {
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "named" | "deterministic",   // ONE OF THESE VALUES
    chunkIds: "named"
  }
};
```